# Using Jquery calling different functions with a singe link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*I would like to use single a href link to call different functions .


On first click it should call first_function() and on second click it should call second_function.
 Like toggling between two functions using same link. Suggest the best way to be done.*

> ***Jquery Code :***

```
$(function() {

 var IntervalId;

 function first_function() {
  //code goes here
 }; 

 function second_function(){  
  //code goes here
 }  

$("#link2").click((function(){
second_function();
}));

$("#link1").click((function(){
first_function();
}));

});
```

> ***Html Code :***

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link2">Call function2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link1">Call function1</a>
```

Comment: Why don't you add that bit directly to the question? :) That's where it belongs.

Comment: what happens to your non js users? The links as you have them will take them no where. Use jquery to enhance the application, not as a tool to make it work.

Comment: Oh, and by the way. It is considerably more effective to ask complete questions right away. Maybe you should take the info from this question, see how far you get with it, and then ask a new question describing the new problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Like toggling between two functions using same link."

```
$("#link1").toggle(
 function first_function() {
  // Code goes here 
 },
 function second_function(){  
  // Code goes here 
 }  
);
```

From the jQuery docs on [`toggle(fn1, fn2,  [fn3, [fn4, [...]]]`)](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle#fnfn2fn3.2Cfn4.2C...):

> Toggle among two or more function calls every other click.

Comment: forgot all about toggleing :)

Comment: http://visualjquery.com/ is quite helpful in finding functions you never knew about.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak for the link . I have updated the question with more info . Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would be

```
var performFirstAction = true;

$(function() {

 function first_function() {
  // Code goes here 
 } 

 function second_function(){  
  // Code goes here 
 }  

 $("#link1").click(function(){
  if(performFirstAction) {
    first_function(); performFirstAction = false; }
  else {
    second_function(); performFirstAction = true; }
 });
});
```

or using toggle as Tomalak mention and well,

```
$(function() {

 function first_function() {
  // Code goes here 
 } 

 function second_function(){  
  // Code goes here 
 }  

 $("#link1").toggle(
   first_function,
   second_function
 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function first_function() {
        // Code goes here 
    }; 

    function second_function(){  
        // Code goes here 
    }

    $("#link").toggle(first_function, second_function);
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- I'm pretty sure that <a> isn't the right tag for this. -->
<button id="link">Toggle between the two functions.</button>
```

Comment: gs Can you explain why button is more right way than <a> tag ?

Comment: <a> is a link which is supposed to open another page instead of executing javascript. You can - of course - use any other element like <span> or <div>.